# Get Schengen visa refused twice. Am I blocked from entry?

Tags: schengen, spain, czech-republic, serial-refusals

I get 2 refusals for a Schengen visa.

The 1st was from Spain 2 years ago despite having all necessary documents to attend a meeting.

The second one was from Czech Republic despite having clear documents with an invitation letter to attend a fellowship but I was applying with my wife and baby.

Does my chance to be accepted in a third country decrease dramatically as I could be blocked from entry to Schengen or doesn't it matter?

Do you think that reapplying to Czech Republic for a second time without my family would be or should I try to apply through another country for a fellowship as Germany would be the best option?

Comment: The answer depends on the reasons given for your refusals.  Can you add this information?